# Raspberry pi:send only last captured image using webcam

Tags: python, windows, raspberry-pi, webcam, putty

I have captured image using webcam and when i press button it sends mail.I use while loop as shown in below code,this code is running perfectly but problem is this program send so many image(also send earlier capured image)while we stop the program to run,so there are so many images attached in one mail only.Now i want program continuonsly running in raspberry pi but still it should be mail only last captured image so what i have to do changes for that?

Thanks in advance.

This is my code:

```
import smtplib
import time
import subprocess
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.MIMEImage import MIMEImage
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

# Define these once; use them twice!
strFrom = 'example@gmail.com'
strTo = 'example@gmail.com'

#create email
# Create the root message and fill in the from, to, and subj$
msgRoot = MIMEMultipart()
msgRoot['Subject'] = 'subject'
msgRoot['From'] = strFrom
msgRoot['To'] = strTo


GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(4, GPIO.IN)
print "press button to send email"
while True:
        input=GPIO.input(4)
        if input == True:
                print "button pressed"
                subprocess.Popen(["fswebcam","-r 640x480", "capture.jpg"])
                time.sleep(2)
                # This example assumes the image is in the current
                # directory
                fp = open('capture.jpg', 'rb')
                msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
                fp.close()
                msgRoot.attach(msgImage)
                # send mail
                s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
                s.starttls()
                s.login('example@gmail.com' , 'password')
                s.sendmail(strFrom, strTo,msgRoot.as_string())
                s.close()
                print "Email sent"
                time.sleep(0.2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    msgRoot.attach(msgImage)   

    msgRoot.set_payload(msImage) #Such modified
```

Because you are using the same copy of the annex has been superimposed on the upswing